# fade() function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript through the book "JavaScript: The Good Parts". One of the examples is a fade function, as below:

```
  1 var fade = function (node) {
  2     var level = 1;
  3     var step = function () {
  4         var hex = level.toString(16);
  5         node.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF' + hex + hex;
  6         if (level < 15) {
  7             level += 1;
  8             setTimeOut(step, 100);
  9         }
 10     };
 11     setTimeOut(step, 100);
 12 };
 13 
 14 fade(document.body);
```

But I didn't get the desired effect. Any idea of what might go wrong?

P.S. This is my .html file. I don't know if this is useful.

```
  1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  2 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  3     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  4 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  5     <head>
  6         <title>My program</title>
  7     </head>
  8     <body>
  9         <pre>
 10             <script type = "text/javascript" src = "program.js"></script>
 11         </pre>
 12     </body>
 13 </html>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: what happened and what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Not sure *The Good Parts* is suitable for learning javascript. Better to learn the language (and browser scripting) first, then use *The Good Parts* to improve your understanding and knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. It's `setTimeout`, with a lower-case "o". Remember to always watch case. You can see your effect live at http://jsbin.com/ezoxed/2/edit.

Be sure, whenever you're debugging your JavaScript, to use the developer console for your browser. Often times this is accessed by pressing F12 on your keyboard. Had you looked there, you would have seen the following message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: setTimeOut is not defined

That being said, enjoy the book. It's a fantastic read!

Comment: WOW thanks! That is really helpful, especially the how-to-debug part. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

yes you have a typo. Please look into the following url for live effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/4HVQw/